# deleting a single space using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I am in the process of creating a batch file that will find a users IP address and write it into a specific place in a file. 
The problem I'm encountering is where I put the ip value there is an extra space where I do not need one.

e.g.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"') do @echo   "IPv4" : "%%f">>txt.properties
```

comes out like this " 10.10.10.555" I'm stumped with how to get rid of that extra space right after the quote.

Comment: You could use "tokens=14" in place of your current modifier....

Answer (score 0):

Capture the variable and use `:~1` to read from the 2nd character:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"`) do (
  set ip=%%f
  @echo "IPv4" : "!ip:~1!">>txt.properties
)
```

Comment: Thank you, have any time to explain what setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion does? It seems like !-indicate a modification to a specified variable, not sure what the : is for either in the !ip:~1!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not set `EnableDelayedExpansion`, if I can help it (I come from an era where you could not always ensure it's availability):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"  IPv4 Address"`) do @for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%g in ("%%f") do @echo "IPv4" : %%g
```

The spaces in front of `IPv4 Address` prevent a false positive on "Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address" that returns a `169` IP address.